# Why badge Constable not awarded to Community

Tags: feature-request, badges, community-user

The badge [Constable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/3108/constable) is awarded to non elected moderators if they moderate for 1 year or more.

**Community** is a moderator, even won the **Not a robot** badge.

Then why wasn't the [Community user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community) awarded with the Constable badge?

Comment: In the past the Community user did have that badge. Unfortunately in 2012 (iirc), in what is since referred to as "the incident", what should have been a simple bot began show symptoms of sentience. As a result of some of its actions at that time (posts about which have since been purged), its badges were taken away as a form of punishment. A harsh step to take, but quite necessary at the time.

Comment: For more details, is there any blog post available @Bart ?

Comment: What's with the frivolous requests, @SagarV?

Comment: I was joking Sagar. ;)

Comment: @Bart, I wonder why it is not awarded?

Comment: @Oded Sorry I didn't understood what you asking? I hear the word for first time `frivolous`

Comment: On a more serious note, the Community user is not a moderator. It's a process with some elevated rights to take actions it otherwise could not, or assume responsibility for actions of others (non-users in particular). And I guess the diamond is mostly there to indicate to others that it's not just some random user poking/editing/voting for posts.

Comment: http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/frivolous

Comment: Some Stack Overflow employees also have the diamond, even though they're not moderators. They have it because their role requires it.Same with Community.

Comment: @Oded got it. First I thought the image can represent the request. Because I am asking why you didn't award the badge. [Removed]

Comment: @S.L.Barth yah I saw many of them holding the diamond but they can not be found on the moderators page. Now I got the reason. (First I thought it is because they are not elected moderators. Now am clear on that.)

Comment: The badge description clearly states "pro-tem moderator". That's someone from the community who has been assigned as a moderator. Your question here can just as well ask why employees with diamonds don't have the badge. The answer is - because neither employees nor "Community" are pro-tem moderators.

Answer (score 15):

The description of the badge is:

> Served as a pro-tem moderator for at least 1 year or through site graduation.

Community (and Stack Overflow employees with diamonds) are not pro-tem moderators and thus not eligible for the badge.

Answer (score 10):

The Community user is not a moderator. Keep in mind that the diamond does not indicate that a user is an elected moderator (or pro-tem moderator). It indicates that a user has certain elevated moderator privileges. Certain employees (though not all) also have the diamond and associated privileges if they need them for their job.

The Community user is a user/process with some elevated privileges to take certain actions it otherwise could not, or to assume the responsibility for certain actions by non-users (either users who had not account at the time, or since have had their account removed).

tl;dr the Community User isn't a moderator, hasn't been a pro-tem moderator, and as such shouldn't get a badge.